# OnBackPressed does not work correctly in some fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

In MainActivity I have next method:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    val onBackPressListener = currentFragmentOnTop() as? OnBackPressListener
    if (onBackPressListener?.onBackPress() != true) super.onBackPressed()
}
```

But sometimes he doesn't work correctly.

For example:
In my `startDestination` fragment I call dialog(bottomMenuDialog) with menuItems, by clicking on which I call fragments:

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.settings_list)
```

Here is code of my nav_graph.xml:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/authorizationsListFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/authorizationsListFragment"
        android:name="com.mandarine.sai.features.authorizations.list.AuthorizationsListFragment"
        android:label="AuthorizationsListFragment">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/settings_list"
            app:destination="@+id/settingsListFragment" />

        <action
            android:id="@+id/connections_list"
            app:destination="@+id/connectionsListFragment" />

        <action
            android:id="@+id/bottom_menu_dialog"
            app:destination="@+id/bottomMenuDialog" />
    </fragment>
```

But I can't click on the back button to go to the start fragment.
Behavior: it opens the start fragment and immediately goes back to the current one, to `settings_list`.

Answer (score 1):

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
  finish()
 }
```

Comment: `activity?.finish()` u mean? this is close application. 
I need to go back to the starting fragment

Comment: can you  clear me  your problem ? i don't get it @Morozov